# Problems with scale and pointAt in SVG.js

Tags: angular, svg, svg.js

I am currently building a project with Angular and SVG.js. I draw several paths and **scale** them. I also use the **pointAt()**-function, which gives me certain points on the path.
However, my problem is that when the paths are scaled, the path (*d-attribute*) does not change, but only a transform (e.g. *transform: matrix(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 115, 115);*) is inserted in the css. As a result, the pointAt()-function no longer works properly and still returns **points on the original path** and not on the scaled one.

Does anyone know if there is a possibility that the pointAt()-function will return points on the scaled path?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add a [mcve] here please?

Comment: Just transform the point with the same matrix you scaled the path with e.g. `path.pointAt(...).transform(path.matrix())`